# WCF proxy always showing an array and not a List<T>

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm using WSSF in Visual studio 2010 sp1 and I'm having an issue with WCF collections. It seems that when I create a service reference and change the advanced setting to use a Generic list instead of an array. I still get arrays when trying to use the collections. I would have to convert the array back and forth to a list whenever i want to add or remove objects.

Does anyone know why? or what i need to change for it to work ok. In the data contract designer, i have two types of collections. One is a "Data Contract Collection", another one is "Primitive Data Type Collection".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WSSF but at a base level WCF ILists are handled as arrays. You would have to manually serialise the DTO as a List. Perhaps that's what's happening underneath the covers?

```
[DataMember]
public IList<Blah> BlahList
{
    get { return blah; }
    set { blah= new List<Blah>(value);
}

private List<Blah> blah;
```

Comment: I would recommend against this since it defeats the purpose of having your property defined as an IList.